# Can I take an asthma inhaler to the US without a prescription?

Tags: usa, health

I'm going to New York, Newark airport, then to Houston airport. I have an inhaler (Ivax Salamol CFC-free inhaler, and a Ventolin Evohaler) but I fly out in less than 12 hours. I don't have a prescription at hand, and don't have time to get one from my doctor. Will this be an issue in either state? And how do I go about this? Because I'll have 2, one will be in my carry-on and one will be in my pocket, because my asthma can flare up at any point.

Comment: I'm not sure about the official rules but anecdotally, I have never had an issue with taking my ventolin inhaler (in carry on) through any of the US airports/states I've been to (including both Newark and Houston)

Comment: If labelled from the pharmacy, you will not have a problem.  If your doctor just gave you sample ones or they were acquired in other creative ways, in theory you could have a problem, but in practice I would expect not, given the nature of these drugs.

Answer (score 2):

The TSA (Transportation Security Administration) actually has [a page specifically about inhalers](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/inhalers):

> Inhalers Carry On Bags: 
>   **Yes** (Special Instructions)
>
> Checked Bags: 
>   **Yes**
>
> TSA allows larger amounts of medically necessary liquids, gels, and
>   aerosols in reasonable quantities for your trip, but you must declare
>   them to TSA officers at the checkpoint for inspection.
>
> We recommend, but do not require, that your medications be labeled to
>   facilitate the security process.

Comment: The special instructions (from following a link on that website) appear to be "separate it out and inform the TSA officer". Seems to me to be more of a way to get >100ml through screening, rather than them really worrying about people transporting medication, but I may have misinterpreted their intention.